# Reset Eclipse Theme

Tags: themes, eclipse, reset

I downloaded and imported an [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/) theme and it did not look good, I believe because I also have Epic installed.  Is there a Reset All?  I'm afraid I will need to re-install. I have tried Restore Defaults on each node in preferences but have not been able to get all of them (like the workspace background color).  Maybe there is a config file to delete?

Answer (score 0):

The top answer on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96981/color-themes-for-eclipse) on StackOverflow describes how to change the theme in Eclipse. There are two files that you want to modify, or in your case restore to their original settings. You should be able to extract those files from the original Eclipse distribution package and replace the modified ones. Of course, back up the current files first just in case.

Comment: i think this would have worked except I have an add-on (EPIC) that has its own settings that override the core settings, and these are what were changed. I started downloading this as well to copy settings but realized at this point I was essentially doing a re-install.  I found that instead, I could just delete (rename) my workspace directory and eclipse will re-create it.